# Creating Generic Definition For Singleton Objects/Forms

Tags: vb.net, generics, inheritance, singleton

I'm tying to create a **generic solution for instantiating my forms** using singleton behavior in `vb.net`. But it's not working anyway and always protecting me to compile:

```
Public Class SingletonGenerator(Of TForm)

    Private _inst As Object

    Public ReadOnly Property Instance As SingletonInstance(Of TForm)
        Get
            If _inst Is Nothing Then
                _inst = New TForm()
            End If
            Return _inst
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

But this error restricts me to continue:

> Error 9   'New' cannot be used on a type parameter that does not have a 'New' constraint.

And I'm not sure if I replace my code with `New Form()` it works as expected (because it create objects of parent `form()` class and may loose some initialization in child class.)

Can somebody please explain why this happen or how can I have singleton instances of objects in an `OOP` way which not require to copy/paste those common lines of code which are used in singleton on every new defined class?

Comment: If you don't have any arguments to pass into the constructor, just add the New constraint. I believe the syntax in VB.NET is `(Of TForm As New)`.

Comment: Where exactly the singleton pattern is applied in this code? I'm confused. With this example you have to have an instance of `SingletonGenerator' for each form you want to work with.

Comment: @Lucero You comment a correct answer and this was what I didn't know "which I can place new keyword as type". Thanks.

Comment: @shadow Yes this is not singleton pattern and not generic and requires definition because I couldn't do what I have in mind but now I got my answer and I can continue what I was trying to make. When I made it successfully I'll place final code into answers maybe useful for someone.

Comment: Check my answer. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convince the compiler that the TForm type in fact has a parameterless constructor so that `New TForm()` can never fail.  That requires [a *constraint*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4xaz66w.aspx).

Not the only thing you need to do, a Form object becomes unusable when it is closed.  And you'll have to create another one to re-display it.  Failure to do so causes an ObjectDisposedException at runtime.  In other words, you should be interested in the Disposed event.  That requires a further constraint, the TForm type parameter always needs to derive from Form.  Required to convince the compiler that it is okay to use the event.  Adding it up:

```
Public Class SingletonGenerator(Of TForm As {Form, New})

    Private _inst As TForm

    Public ReadOnly Property Instance As TForm
        Get
            If _inst Is Nothing Then
                _inst = New TForm()
                AddHandler _inst.Disposed, Sub() _inst = Nothing
            End If
            Return _inst
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Do be a bit careful with this, you are painting yourself into a corner.  You can only ever use this code to create form objects whose constructor takes no argument.  In practice you may find they often need one.

Comment: You're great man, I never knew I could define generic classes by this pattern: `Of TForm As {Form, New}`.

Comment: About constructors I'm sure I'll not use parameters for forms and about form dispose I'll handle it by hiding rather than close. This was exactly what I was searching for and I didn't know, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
Module Startup

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim f As Form = FormsManager.Instance.GetForm(Of Form1)()

        f.ShowDialog()

        Dim f1 As Form = FormsManager.Instance.GetForm(Of Form1)()

        f1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class FormsManager
    Private Shared _formsManager As FormsManager
    Private _forms As List(Of Form)

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As FormsManager
        Get
            If (_formsManager Is Nothing) Then
                _formsManager = New FormsManager
            End If

            Return _formsManager
        End Get
    End Property


    Private Sub New()
        If _forms Is Nothing Then _forms = New List(Of Form)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetForm(Of T As {Form, New})() As Form
        Dim f As Form = _forms.Where(Function(o) o.GetType = GetType(T)).SingleOrDefault

        If f Is Nothing Then
            f = New T
            _forms.Add(f)
        End If

        Return f
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code but this was not what I meant and Hans Passants answer helped me to complete my idea and I'll share it now; I thinks it's more simple and flexible than doing it this way. +1 for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally produced (a generic singlton forms generator):

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

<HideModuleName()> _
Public Module SingletoneForms

    <Extension> _
    Public Function GetInstance(Of TForm As {Form, New})(ByRef obj As TForm) As TForm
        Return SingletonForm(Of TForm).Instance
    End Function

    Public Class SingletonForm(Of TForm As {Form, New})

        Private Shared WithEvents _inst As TForm

        Public Shared Property Instance As TForm
            Get
                If _inst Is Nothing Then
                    SetInstance(New TForm())
                End If
                Return _inst
            End Get
            Set(value As TForm)
                SetInstance(value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Shared Sub SetInstance(ByVal newInst As TForm)
            If _inst IsNot Nothing Then
                RemoveHandler _inst.FormClosing, AddressOf FormClosing
            End If
            _inst = newInst
            AddHandler _inst.FormClosing, AddressOf FormClosing
        End Sub

        Private Shared Sub FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
            If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
                e.Cancel = True
                _inst.Hide()
            Else
                _inst = Nothing
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class

End Module
```

and call it simply this way:

```
frmMain.GetInstance().Show()
Form1.GetInstance().Show()
Form1.GetInstance().Hide()
Form2.GetInstance().ShowDialog()
```